# centering image html/css/tsx

Tags: css, image, centering

I'm trying to center a simple image on my front page.

```js
import Image from 'next/image'
import styles from './page.module.css'
import Link from 'next/link'




export default function Home() {
  return (


 <main className={styles.main}>
 <main className={styles.logo}></main>     

 <a href="./webadminpage" className="logo"> <img src="/logocarel.svg" width={700} height={1000} alt="carellogo" />  </a>

</main>
  
  )
}
```

CSS

```css
.main {
  background-color: rgb(143, 192, 67);
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.logo {

  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 50%;



}
```

Comment: Not a fix but note that the [<img>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-img-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what the goal is for having a `main` tag inside another `main` tag but the `a` tag should probably be contained in it. Also, it is generally advised to have only one main tag so either change it into a `div` tag or any other tag.
Like this:

```
<main className={styles.main}>
 <div className={styles.logo}>     
 <a href="./webadminpage" className="logo"> <img src="/logocarel.svg" width={700} height={1000} alt="carellogo" />  </a>
</div>
</main>
```

Then, try this in your `.main` CSS:

```
.main {
  background-color: rgb(143, 192, 67);
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Hope this helps.